# What metrics can I use to measure app performance?

Tags: android, performance

I have typical android app that loads some data from server and dislaing it. And my task is to make it faster, improve responsiveness and so on. But to understand that it is really faster I need to know performance that was before.
For example if it were web site I could measure page load speed and so on. But what metrics could be for Android application?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do those measurements here: use log statements to see which steps take the most time (the actual request, parsing it, displaying it,...)

I would also do specific checks for mobile, like making sure as little as possible is being done on the main thread. Also do some 'load tests' by letting your server return large amounts of data and making sure this does not make your app unresponsive

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the question is? You want to make it faster. So you determine what you want to improve, for instance, the first screen. Then you measure what makes it slow (it will be doing several things, like retrieve content, maybe parse it, display it). Determine what is the slowest factor, see if you can improve that, rinse, repeat.

So what metrics? "time".

Comment: I'll ask it in another way. I need to make it faster, but I don't know what is the reason of slowness. What tools I can use to determine weak places except Log (to measure time for example)? I tried to see some useful information with systrace but without success

Comment: The tool you need _is_ log. one way or the other, either log.d or your own log.